# Neo4j ElasticSearch integration

Tags: python, elasticsearch, neo4j

http://neo4j.com/developer/elastic-search/#_push_to_elasticsearch says that we can use afterCommit notification method to push data into ES.

Can anybody help me how to do it in python?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do it in Python, only Java. There are modules that do it for you like https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-to-elasticsearch

Comment: I tried it but not able to integrate it. Any tutorials to do it?